# Woocommerce API - Create Order With Float Quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Unfortunately, in my store all of the product quantities are in float.
I used the below code to accept float value as a quantity in my website.

```
// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');

// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');
```

But, when I trying to create a order using API from my mobile app is not accepting the float value.

```
$woocommerce->post('orders', $getData);
```

anybody help me, how can I create a order using woocommerce api to accept float quantities.

Answer (score 5):

> Unfortunately, you **can't** achieve this with the latest API version. You can try any of the solution given below but **NOT recommended**.

**Solution 1:** Use [Legacy API](https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library).

**Solution 2:** Directly change `'type' => integer` to `'type' => float` (around 1190) in 'woocommerce/includes/api/class-wc-rest-orders-controller.php' which is responsible for the quantity (but note that you need to change every time you upgrade the plugin).

```
'quantity'     => array(
    'description' => __( 'Quantity ordered.', 'woocommerce' ),
    'type'        => 'float', // change here
    'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit' ),
),
```

Comment: Not sure why my answer was down-voted since I already mentioned that the solutions were not recommended ones and there was no proper way to achieve this thing other than the above :(